# Random delay inside a smart contract function

Tags: erc-20, tokens, oracles, binance-smart-chain, optimization

So, I'm trying to implement an anti-sniping feature that would make the users wait a random time between 0-12 seconds - specifically 0, 3, 6, 9 or 12 seconds because my smart contract would be on BSC. And the delay is in chunks of 3 because I noticed a new block is mined every 3s.

I was wondering what the most gas-efficient way to introduce such a delay to the smart contract is?

I think using a while loop and comparing block.timestamp with when the tx was initiated would cost a lot of gas. Looking for optimal solutions!